# org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.embeddedMongoServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flapdoodle-embed-mongo

when I'm trying to update my spring-boot project to 2.7.x from 2.0.1, I'm getting the following error...
also, I'm using the flapdoodle embded dependemcy with version 3.0.0 for my testcases.

nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.embeddedMongoServer

**DEPENDENCIES**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
        <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        <version>1.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
        <version>4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by upgrading your flapdoodle version to 3.3.0.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also make sure you have the following dependency for your Spring Boot version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.8</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using flapdoodle 3.3.0 with Spring Boot 2.7.8 and it is working fine.